# Default values for enums using the default keyword?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Anyone knows the default value for enums using the default keywords as in:

```
MyEnum myEnum = default(MyEnum);
```

Would it be the first item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the value produced by `(myEnum)0`. For example:

```
enum myEnum
{
  foo = 100
  bar = 0,
  quux = 1
}
```

Then `default(myEnum)` would be `myEnum.bar` or the first member of the enum with value 0 if there is more than one member with value 0.

The value is `0` if no member of the enum is assigned (explicitly or implicitly) the value 0.

Comment: Thanks, but what if there is no 0 defined? But they were 100, 99 and 1?

Comment: Then it is 0. I updated my answer accordingly. See related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529929/choosing-the-default-value-of-an-enum-type-without-having-to-change-values

Comment: If there's no 0 defined, the value is still 0.  Remember than an enum is really just a thin typesafe wrapper around an integral type, giving you the ability to reference integral values by name.

Comment: Thanks, so if there is no enum 0, you mean the value assigned really be 0 as in int (0)?

Comment: @Jim: got it now from your comment.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to understand your question, but the default value for an enum is zero, which may or may not be a valid value for the enumeration.

If you want `default(MyEnum)` to be the first value, you'd need to define your enumeration like this:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
   First = 0,
   Second,
   Third
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression `default(T)` is the equivalent of saying `(T)0` for a generic parameter or concrete type which is an `enum`.  This is true whether or not the `enum` defines an entry that has the numeric value 0.

```
enum E1 {
  V1 = 1;
  V2 = 2;
}

...

E1 local = default(E1);
switch (local) {
  case E1.V1:
  case E1.V2:
    // Doesn't get hit
    break;
  default:
    // Oops
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

slapped this into vs2k10.....

with:

```
 enum myEnum
 {
  a = 1,
  b = 2,
  c = 100
 };



 myEnum  z = default(en);
```

produces: `z == 0` which may or may not be a valid value of your enum (in this case, its not)

thus sayeth visual studio 2k10