# ASP.NET MVC Html.EnumDropDownListFor Selected Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums

I am using `EnumDropDownListFor` in ASP.NET MVC:

```
 @Model.PhoneNumberType

 @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.PhoneNumberType, new {@class = "form-control"})
```

This does not pre-select the value of the `enum` in the drop down list.
If I just Display the `enum` value it will Show the right `enum` value.
The DropDown is always set to the first value in the drop down, but not to the value of the `enum` field.

How can I configure `EnumDropDownListFor` to pre-select the drop down with the value of the `enum` field?

Answer (score 5):

The only thing you should do, is to set the enum value when you are passing your model.

A little example (Test2 ll be selected by default) :

**Model**

```
    public class ModelTest
    {
        public EnumTest EnumTest { get; set; }
    }

    public enum EnumTest
    {
        Test1,
        Test2,
        Test3
    }
```

**View** :

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.ModelTest

<div>
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.EnumTest, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

**Controller** :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ModelTest model = new ModelTest {EnumTest = EnumTest.Test2};
        return View("View",model);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this means I would have to introduce a new entry into my enum called PleaseSelect no?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23085333/957950) for a good way to set an empty default option (hint: use a nullable enum).

Comment: how do you get the selected value in the controllre out of this enum on POST