# Possibility to have Range data annotation validation only on form submit?

Tags: c#, forms, validation, range, data-annotations

I have been searching through the stackoverflow website for an answer to my question, but I couldn't find a proper solution. So I hope I can get the solution this way.

**Situation:**
I have a form with several fields; 2 of them are required: one of them is an EnumDropDownListFor which has an extra 'empty option'.

**Problem:**
The validation of the dropdownlist triggers on the change event of the dropdown/when the empty option has been selected.

**Wanted behavior:**
Only validate the dropdownlist when the form is submitted and NOT on the change event.

Here is my code:

```
public class SearchOrderViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Supplier", ResourceType = typeof(SearchOrderStrings))]
    public string Supplier { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SearchOrderStrings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "OrderTypeRequired")]
    [Display(Name = "OrderType", ResourceType = typeof(SearchOrderStrings))]
    public OrderTypeEnum OrderType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "PurchasingReason", ResourceType = typeof(SearchOrderStrings))]
    public int PurchasingReason { get; set; }
}

public enum OrderTypeEnum
    {
        OpenOrder = 1,
        ClosedOrder = 2
    }
```

**Index.cshtm**

```
<div id="divExternalSupplierSearch" class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Supplier)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Supplier)
    <div id="divDropdown">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Supplier,
        Model.SupplierCodes, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divOrderTypes" class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderType)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderType)
    <div id="divDropdown">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.OrderType, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divPurchasingReasons" class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PurchasingReason)
    <div id="divDropdown">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PurchasingReason, Model.PurchasingReasons, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

If more information is needed, let me know.

Thanks

**EDIT (Solution):**

By combining @Elmer Dantas answer and trying some things, I found that I could become the wanted behaviour by removing the [Range] data-annotation and making the OrderType property in my SearchOrderViewModel nullable.

So this code is only validating the OrderType value on submit of the form:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "OrderType", ResourceType = typeof(SearchOrderStrings))]
public OrderTypeEnum? OrderType { get; set; }
```

Apparently the

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SearchOrderStrings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "OrderTypeRequired")]
```

data-annotation was checking if the value was valid on the change event of the dropdownlist. By making the property nullable and just keeping the [Required] data-annotation, I could keep the validation to only be triggered when submitting the form.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878673/html-enumdropdownlistfor-showing-a-default-text) could help you.

Comment: I looked into the post you linked and changed the OrderType property in my SearchOrderViewModel to be nullable:
    public OrderTypeEnum? OrderType { get; set; }
but It did not do the trick

Comment: you've had the default value?? `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.OrderType, "Select an Order", new { @class = "form-control" })select? `

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry...I was asking if you added the "default value" when none of the orders were selected..like "select an order"...the first option of dropdown...

Comment: No I did not add a default option, since a blank value is enough to show on my screen. I could add a default option " - - - " to make it more clear tot he user, but it's not necessary in my case.