# Select selected value in drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I have an `enum` which looks something like

```
public enum Department
{
    Admin,
    HR,
    Marketing,
    Sales
}
```

From this I am trying to create a drop down list in the controller and I do it like

```
public SelectList GetDepartmentDropDownList(string departmentName = null)
{
    var departments = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Department));
    SelectList ddl = new SelectList(departments);

    return ddl;
}
```

Which works fine. But as you can see I can pass in the opitional parameter. This optional parameter is passed in when the dropdown value is saved to the database and the user comes back to edit the section. What I am trying to achieve is whatever the user originally selected, when they come back on the edit screen that particular item is select i.e if they selected `HR` when they come back `HR` should be selected.

If I do `new SelectList(departments, departmentName, departmentName);` I get the following error:

> DataBinding: Enums.Department' does not contain a property with the name 'HR'

Can someone suggest how to achieve this please.

In the view I am making using of `Html.DropDownListFor()` as

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Department, Model.DepartmentDdl, "Please select a Department", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
```

The property in my model is

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DepartmentDdl { get; set; }
```

And in the controller create action I do

```
model.DepartmentDdl = GetDepartmentDropDownList();
```

And in the controller edit action I do

```
model.DepartmentDdl = GetDepartmentDropDownList(departmentName); //department name here is read from the db
```

Comment: Its the value of the property your binding to which determines what is selected. Show your view and the property your binding to (you need to set it in the model before you pass it to the view)

Comment: Just set the value of `Department` to `Department.HR` in the GET method, and it will be  selected (there is no point in your parameter in the `GetDepartmentDropDownList()` method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878673/html-enumdropdownlistfor-showing-a-default-text)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've tried your suggestion but it still does not select the value.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've got it to work, would you mind putting it down as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model binding works by binding to the value of your property. You need to set the value of property `Department` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view, for example

```
var model = new YourModel
{
    Department = Department.HR,
    DepartmentDdl = GetDepartmentDropDownList()
};
return View(model);
```

Note that there is no need for your parameter in the `GetDepartmentDropDownList()` method. Internally, the `DropDownListFor()` method builds a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and sets the `Selected` value of each `SelectListItem` based on the property your binding to (i.e. setting it in the `SelectList` constructor is ignored).