# ASP.NET MVC Html Helper: Adding a validation in an enum ddl

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-validation

I'm pretty new in ASP.NET MVC. And I'm very sorry for this question.

What my goal is: To add a validation using Html Helper of ASP.NET MVC on an enum ddl.

#### Model

```
public enum SampleEnum { 
    Active = 1, Inactive = 2, Pending = 3
}
public class SampleClass { 
    [Required]
    public SampleEnum sampleEnum{get;set;}
}
```

#### View

```
<form action="url" method="post">
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.sampleEnum, "-- Select Sample Enum --", new { @class = "custom-select custom-select-sm" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.sampleEnum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

Once I clicked Submit, it doesn't validate my form but rather continue to submit it. 
P.S. As much as possible, I would want to use model validation instead of jquery-validation. 
Thanks,

Comment: Use DropDownListFor instead of EnumDropDownListFor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should make sure that you include the validation and unobtrusive libraries

jquery.validate.js

jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

in your main layout view

[image]

if you don't have the files then you can install them from nuget

[image]

**Update** : 
if you need only to use server side validation then you need just to Replace the data annotation for required field from `[Required]` to `[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "This is required")]` 
that's because `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor` will always send **0** if user didn't select any of the options of the drop down list, and that value will considered as valid.
check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21882471/4749790)

the filed decoration should look like the following 
[image]

and please consider putting a valid action url for the form 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, But I would want to use ASP.NET MVC html helper validation not jquery-validation.