# How are the default values for numeric types chosen (when no identifiers are given) by the enum in C#?

Tags: c#, enums

When I use the code:

```
enum Programs {BSE, BCS, BSDS}
```

the default value "BSE" is chosen, but for:

```
enum Year: ushort {year1=2021, year2=2022}
```

the code does not give the default year of 2021.
How do I solve this? Is there any way for choosing **numeric** types in enums?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing the default value of an Enum type without having to change values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529929/choosing-the-default-value-of-an-enum-type-without-having-to-change-values)

Comment: An `enum`'s default value is always `0` because it is an integer underneath. Using `enum` for years seems to be a bit of bad idea anyway

Comment: Do note that `Year y = (Year) 1984` is completely legal, and does not seem unreasonable. Setting "2021" as the "base year" can be done without an enum, and if it needs to be enforced, probably should be done without an enum.

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum

> The default value of an enumeration type `E` is the value produced by expression `(E)0`, even if zero doesn't have the corresponding enum member

There is another popular answer here  [Choosing the default value of an Enum type without having to change values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529929/choosing-the-default-value-of-an-enum-type-without-having-to-change-values) using attributes, but that won't change the value of the unassigned enum type.